# R code help needed for map legend not in the right position

Tags: r, plot, shiny, legend

I am learning shiny R and am trying to run an example from this page on R studio:

https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson5/

I am trying to run the example below, which does not need any shiny knowledge yet:

Step 1: download `helpers.R` at https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson5/census-app/helpers.R

Step 2: install packages `maps` and `mapproj`

Step 3: download data `counties.rds` at https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson5/census-app/data/counties.rds

Step 4: put `counties.rds` in the folder `./census-app/data`, put `helpers.R` in the folder `./census-app`. Here `./` is my project folder.

Step 5: Run the following code in console:

```
library(maps)
library(mapproj)

source("census-app/helpers.R")
counties <- readRDS("census-app/data/counties.rds")
percent_map(counties$white, "darkgreen", "% White")
```

I should be getting a graph like this:

[image: percentage of white across the counties of AU]

Instead I get something like this:

[image: same map but legends are off the position]

I tried different version of R (R 3.4.4, 3.5.1, 3.5.3) and it is still not working.

I figure might have to do with the code inside the package `maps` and `mapproj`, but I do not know how to adjust it, or if I am supposed to.

Comment: Try adjusting the `cex` argument: `legend(..., cex.0.5)`

Comment: The `legend` is built into the `percent_map` function in `helpers.R`. You could review the code used in this function [here](https://github.com/chendaniely/shiny-official--tutorial/blob/master/census-app/helpers.R) and adapt for your own function, which may give you may control and flexibility in terms of `legend` (e.g., size, location) and other features. You could change `cex` as suggested by @Edward to change character size in legend, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

An update:

I think I found the solution.

It will make a difference whether I was running the percent_map() with Rstudio full screen, or half/regular screen.

It will give me the write output when the code was run under full screen.

Weird but good to know.